# Is this a cyclic reference?

Tags: java, generics, javafx-2

Please consider this an attempt to understand the api and not questioning the judgement of the architect.

[JavaFX Event](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/Event.html)

Referring to the constructor of the `javafx.event.Event`, I need to pass an `EventType` of `Event` to instantiate an `Event`. Am I reading this right ? If so, wouldn't this be a cyclic reference ?

Comment: As far as I see on the API docs, Event depends on EventType, but EventType does not depend on Event, so there is no cyclic reference.

Answer (score 3):

No its not, because generic parameters are resolved *at compile time*. At runtime there's nothing being passed into the `Event` constructor but an `EventType`.

Answer (score 2):

Not in the sense that you mean.

An EventType instance can refer to other EventType instances, but not to Event instances.  Take a look at the constructor and methods of EventType, paying close attention to the method / constructor parameter and return types.

Answer (score 1):

This is not cyclical, but it really, really takes a lot of thinking to understand.

From the javadoc you provided:

```
Event(EventType<? extends Event> eventType) 
Construct a new Event with the specified event type.
```

The `EventType<? extends Event>` should be read as "An EventType that works with a certain type of Event".

Here is another SO answer that does a better job of explaining the `<? extends Class>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3009779/463196

For example, let's say we have a `FooEvent` that extends `Event`.  We would then have an `EventType` that works with `FooEvent`.

Also, if you look at the JavaDoc for [`EventType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/EventType.html), it says:

```
This class represents a specific event type associated with an Event.
```