# Is there some special meaning to the text "<? >"?

Tags: java, generics, extends

```
private final Class<? extends FragmentActivity> activityClass;
```

I understand the definition except for the `<? >` part.

Is there some reason for the extends to be enclosed in that special text?

Comment: Use the search function.

Comment: You'll probably be interested in reading the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the question mark in Java generics' type parameter mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that is [wild card character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) that says any it can take any type which `extends` `FragmentActivity`

Comment: Not any type. *Some type* that is or extends `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of [Java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) and it means the type of activityClass extends FragmentActivity.