# Making an ArrayList that contains the object and its' extension

Tags: java, object, methods, arraylist

So basically I've created two classes "public class A" and "public class B extends A". I want to create an ArrayList that contains both objects and be able to access both of their methods. Is this possible and how could I do it?

Comment: You have an `Animal` and a `Dog` (which is an animal) class and you want an `arraylist` to hold both of them. What should be type of arraylist ? `Animal` or `Dog` ? This is best I can do without giving you an actual answer.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean) might answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ArrayList<B>` won't hold objects of type `A`, so that can't work.

An `ArrayList<? extends A>` won't work either.  The compiler won't know which subtype of `A` (or `A` itself) it really is, so it won't allow adding anything but `null` with the `add` method.

Generally the best you can do is to use an `ArrayList<A>`.

There could be methods that are defined in `A` but not `B`.  Here `B` simply inherits the `A` method and can be called using an `A` reference.

There could be methods that are defined in both `A` and `B`.  Here `B` overrides `A`'s method. Polymorphism indicates that `B`'s method will be called on objects whose runtime type is `B`.

There could be methods that are defined only in `B`.  With an `A` reference they are inaccessible.  But at runtime you can check the type with `instanceof`:

```
for (A a : arrayList)
{
   if (a instanceof B)
   {
      B b = (B) a;
      b.methodSpecificToB();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<A> myArray;
```

This array list will hold objects of type A and type B.