# Type safety: Unchecked cast when extending generics

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method

```
private ResponseEntity<? extends ResourceSupport> createResponse(boolean isError) {
    if(isError){
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResource>((ErrorResource) new ErrorResource());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport>(new ResourceSupport());
}
```

I call this method to get the error resource

```
ResponseEntity<ErrorResource> e = (ResponseEntity<ErrorResource>) createResponse(logoutResult, userId);
System.out.println(e.getError());
```

When I do this I get this error:

```
"Type safety: Unchecked cast from ResponseEntity<capture#1-of ? extends ResourceSupport> to ResponseEntity<ErrorResource>"
```

Is there a way to cast the object without suppressing the error message?

Comment: you could wrap it with an `instanceof` check

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the question mark in Java generics' type parameter mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean)

Answer (score 3):

You use the same method to return apples and oranges instances. At runtime, because of java's type erasure, the system has no way of knowing if that cast is allowed or not, hence the warning. You have 2 ways to avoid it:

a) Create 2 different methods:

```
private ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport> createResponse() {
    return new ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport>(new ResourceSupport());
}

private ResponseEntity<ErrorResource> createErrorResponse() {
    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResource>(new ErrorResource());
}
```

b) Make the method fully generic by passing the actual `ResourceSupport` instance as parameter:

```
private <T extends ResourceSupport> ResponseEntity<T> createResponse(T resource) {
    return new ResponseEntity<T>(resource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: don't try to cast to `ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport>`, but leave the type as is like `ResponseEntity<? extends ResourceSupport>`:

```
ResponseEntity<? extends ResourceSupport> e = createResponse(logoutResult, userId);
System.out.println(e.getError());
```

The types are `ResponseEntity<ErrorResource>` and `ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport>` cannot be assigned to eachother (try it).

But your original code tried to do just that - in the case that there is no error, your `createResponse` method returns a `new ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport>(new ResourceSupport())` but you try to cast that to a `ResponseEntity<ErrorResource>`, which is not allowed.