# Java Comparator syntax works, but why?

Tags: java, syntax, comparator

I am using a [Java Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort an ArrayList of `SomeClass` items. It works just fine, no problems. What I'm curious about is the syntax. Given:

```
 public static class PrioritizedPendingListComparator implements Comparator<SomeClass> {

        @Override
        public int compare(SomeClass o1, SomeClass o2) {
        ...
        }
```

And then, some time later,

```
private ArrayList<SomeClass> pendingList = new ArrayList<>(); 

... // fill it up with entries

Collections.sort(pendingList, new SomeClass.PrioritizedPendingListComparator());
```

I use `new SomeClass.PrioritizedPendingListComparator()` as the second argument to `Collections.sort()`. My comparator, `PrioritizedPendingListComparator`, is `static` so I don't expect to have to use `new`.

1. Why can I not just use `SomeClass.PrioritizedPendingListComparator`
   e.g. why do I need the `new`?
2. How would I know this from reading the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-)?

Comment: Explain your rationale for not having to use `new` with `static` nested types. Do you know what `new` is? What do you think it does? Why do you think so?

Comment: `static inner class` doesn't mean that this is a `static` instance of the class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: I think you're confusing making a class static with making a method static.  It's not at all the same thing.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: For any folks, like me, who don't have the appropriate Java vocabulary to successfully search for information on  `Comparator <? super T> c` without ending up with non-relevant information about the ternary operator, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SomeClass.PrioritizedPendingListComparator` is a class.  You need an instance of it so you have to use `new`

When you define `public static class` the `static` means it doesn't implicitly have a reference to the outer class, but you still have to create it in the normal way.

One way to avoid `new` is to use an `enum`.

```
public enum PrioritizedPendingListComparator implements Comparator<SomeClass> {
    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public int compare(SomeClass o1, SomeClass o2) {
    ...
    }
```

later

```
 Collections.sort(pendingList, SomeClass.PrioritizedPendingListComparator.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: Singleton enum classes are awesome.

Comment: If you don't agree with my dupe closure feel free to reopen, I'm only 95% sure.

Comment: *Stateless* singleton enums are awesome.

Comment: @durron597 dup is reasonable, but in this case I thought there was more to add.

Comment: You can also import ```SomeClass.PrioritizedPendingListComparator``` and then use it without the ```SomeClass.``` prefix

Comment: I guess my big question is why I need an instance. Looking at the method signature `public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` I expected to pass it a type (or template) to sort with, not an instance of a sorter. (Yes, I'm fairly new to Java...)

Comment: In other words, how do I read `<? super T>`?  :-)

Comment: In this sort of case, I tend to go with an anonymous inline class: `public static final FOO_COMPARATOR = new Comparator() { ...`

Comment: @kmort when you see `Comparator` or indeed any other type, you have to pass a reference to an instance of that type.  The only time you don't do this is when you you pass a primitive.

Comment: @kmort In short, Java only has references to instances and primitives.  This is no way to pass a type without passing either an instance of that type or an instance of a `Class` which refers to that type.