# Java generics Enum subtyping Interface

Tags: java, generics, types, enums

Given the following setup:

```
  public class TestType {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Constants> list = new ArrayList<>();
    accept(list); //Does not compile
  }

  static void accept(Iterable<MyInterface> values) {
    for (MyInterface value : values) {
      value.doStuff();
    }
  }
}

interface MyInterface<T> {
  T doStuff();
}

enum Constants implements MyInterface<Integer> {
  ONE, TWO, THREE;

  @Override
  public Integer doStuff() {
    return ordinal();
  }
}
```

Why won't the compiler accept the list as parameter to accept()?

`List` extends `Iterable` via `Collection` so that isn't the problem.

On the other hand, the compiler tells me that
`incompatible types: java.util.List<enums.Constants> cannot be converted to java.lang.Iterable<enums.MyInterface>`

But Constants IS  a MyInterface... isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with how Generics work. Specifically, Generics are non-reified... meaning that the compiler will not see an `Iterable<enum.Constants>` as an `Iterable<enum.MyInterface>` even if Constants is a sub-class of MyInterface.

However, there is a way to get around it:  [Generic wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3009779/15880).

If you change `static void accept(Iterable<MyInterface> values)` to `static void accept(Iterable<? extends MyInterface> values)`, it *should* work.

Comment: That does indeed work. Will accept the answer as soon as SO let's me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Iterable<? extends MyInterface>` instead of `Iterable<MyInterface>` because even though `Constants` is a subtype of `MyInterface`, `Iterable<Constants>` is not a subtype of `Iterable<MyInterface>` - and I'll show you why:

If it was so (let's use `List` instead of `Iterable` for the next example), I would be able to do this:

```
List<Constant> constantsList = new ArrayList<Constants>(); // list of constants
List<MyInterface> ifaceList = constantsList; // you said this would be OK ...
// assume MyOtherImplementation is another implmentation of MyInterface
ifaceList.add(new MyOtherImplementation()); // OK, MyOtherImplementation implements MyInterface
Constant myConst = constantsList.get(0); // Oops! I just got an instance of MyOtherImplementation from List<Constant> - not cool.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic types do not inherit this way, although it may seem counter-intuitive at first glance. Using `Iterable<? extends MyInterface>` will allow you to use any `Iterable` (e.g., a `List`) of a type that extends `MyInterface` (e.g. `Constants`).