# What is the parameterized type of this Constructor in Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

What is the parameterized type of this Constructor in Java reflection?

```
java.lang.reflect.Constructor[] constructors = Stock.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
```

I've tried `Constructor<Stock>[]`, `Constructor<Stock.class>[]`, and `Constructor<Class>[]`.

Comment: I think it refers to the fact that somewhere, you don't use any angle brackets at all.  Try `<?>`.

Comment: What is the return type of `getDeclaredConstructors`?

Comment: Ok, thanks I get it now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `getDeclaredConstructors()` is `<?>` which is just any type.

```
Constructor<?>[] constructors = Stock.class.getDeclaredConstructors();
```

More info:
[What does the question mark in Java generics' type parameter mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean)