# Java Generics: Adding elements to Set<?> , Set<? extends Integer> and Set<? super Integer>

Tags: java

So I was revising some Java concepts and i found out i don't completly understand generics in the most 'complicated' cases. I have around 3 months of Java classes and an exam soon so I would appreciate any help!

In the attached example i dont get why 1) and 2) are invalid.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: For future: please do not paste images with code!

Comment: Oh got it, thanks! I'm new here so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Covariance, Invariance and Contravariance explained in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the question mark in Java generics' type parameter mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean)

Comment: new Set<Integer>()? what? That code is also invalid, you can't instantiate an interface

Comment: I understand what the ? means i just don't understand what assignments are allowed and why the others aren't.

Comment: @POrekhov The code ist most likely copied of a textbook or something and used to understand the **conecept** of generics. Not the instantiation of a `Set`.It has nothing to do with the real issue.

Comment: @POrekhov my bad, in this example i have noted in my papers that Set is a user defined class that the teacher created to show these examples.

Its "public class Set<T> {  (...) }"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think about this quite easily. A `List<? extends SomeClass>` will **always** produce an implementation of `SomeClass`. See the following example:

```
List<Integer> ints = new Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
List<? extends Number> nums = ints; // this does work
Integer i = nums.get(0); // this doesn't
Number num = nums.get(0); // this does again
nums.add(5); // this doesn't too
```

You see that `nums` holds a reference to `ints`. Because `Integer` extends `Number`. And if you read the `nums`-list you'll always get a `Number` out.

This holds true for every superclass-subclass relationship.

**But**: you can't write to the `nums` list. That is, because you don't *exactly* know what list actually is referenced by `nums` in the above example it was a list of `Integer`s, you just know what to expect from the list when you read it.

---

The same is for `List<? super SomeClass>` which is the invert of the above. It will always **consume** any implementations of `SomeClass`. See again the example:

```
List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>();
List<? super String> strings = objs; // this does work
strings.add("Some String"); // this works
String string = strings.get(0); // this doesn't
Object object = strings.get(0); // this does again
```

Now we only know that every element of type `String` and more specific can be put into the `Strings` list. As this is the invert of the above. You don't know what you will get, if you try to read the list. You can just read `Object`s but you will never know their actual class.

---

This is generally called PECS, which stands for: Producer `extends` Consumer `super`. More about this topic can be read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super?rq=1)

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking your time into answering this so well!

So if i have a "List<? extends SomeClass> list" i cannot add ANYTHING into that list ? I can only make the list = someListThatExtendedSomeClass ? This seems bad for most applications, no ?

The same going for the super, if we can only add to those lists, how do we read from them?

Edit: after carefully reading the PECS question you linked i think i got it. This is used when we want our methods to be more flexible but outside those methods we do know what the list holds and can act on that.

Comment: @juliocas thats right. You commonly don't instantiate a list with extends or super. As you said you accept those lists, or any other generix class mostly in methods. This makes also your intentions clear, what you're doing with that passed in list. If the parameter uses `? extends` then you explicitly say that you only want to read, and the other way arround with `? super` of course

Comment: Just one more thing, In the last line of the example, why am i not allowed to store an Object in the set ?

Comment: @juliocas A `Set<? extends Number>` doesn't know what implementation it holds. It could hold a `Set<Integer>`, but also a `Set<BigDecimal>`. So the compiler doesn't really know what *exactly* is stored, he just knows what to expect *at least* from the set. I hope this answers your question

Comment: The example was `Set<? super Integer> set = new Set<Integer>();` and then `set.add(1.0); // INVALID!!!` and `set.add(new Object()); //INVALID!!!` Not being able to put the double in there i get but shouldnt the object be allowed?

Comment: @juliocas No, because you still have an implementation of a `new Set<Integer>()` right? You're not allowed to write an `Object` to `Set<? extends Integer>` as you're not allowed to write said object to a simple `Set<Integer>`

Comment: Oh i get it, having a `Set<? super Integer>` means that i can be a Set<Object>, not that it can store Object objects in it. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: @juliocas glad I could help you understand this. I myself had really problems with this in the beginning :)