# Difference between Class<? extends A> vs just A

Tags: java, generics

```
Class<? extends A> classB
```

vs

```
A classB
```

What's the difference here? Is it just that the first one is an instance of the `Class` and the second is an instance of the actual `Object`?

Comment: Could you extend your examples to provide a little more context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the question mark in Java generics' type parameter mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean)

Comment: @Phil the accepted answer there states "A class/interface that extends `A`." When my question is asking what the difference is when that answer can be said about `A classB` as well. `classB` can also be "A class/interface that extends `A`."

Comment: @Phil That is definitely not a duplicate of this question

Comment: Alright. There's a reason it says "possible".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Class<? extends A>` and `A` are completely two different types.

A variable of type `Class<? extends A>` contains information about a *class*. The class can be `A` or any class that extends `A`, depending on the value of the variable. Things you can do with a `Class<? extends A>` variable includes: getting all the field names declared in the class, getting all the method names declared in the class, getting the super class of the class, and many others.

A variable of type `A` refers to an instance of `A`. If you declared a non-static method called `foo` in the class `A`, then you can call `foo` directly with this variable:

```
yourVariable.foo();
```

You can't directly do this if `yourVariable` is of type `Class<? extends A>`.

See the difference here? `Class<? extends A>` is kind of like a "metatype" whose instances contain information about a type (this type can be `A` or a subclass of `A`), whereas `A` is the type you declared. An instance of `A` represents whatever thing the class is modelled after. An instance of a `Bicycle` class represents a bicycle. It may have methods like `pedal` and `turn` and fields like `durability`. An instance of `Class<? extends Bicycle>` will tell you things like: in the Bicycle class, there is a field called `durability`, and there is a method called `pedal`.

Basically, "meta" is the keyword here. `Class` is a class that represents a class.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The first

```
Class<? extends A> classB
```

defines a member which has the type `Class` which *represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application* [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

So you can write

```
classB = A.class;
classB = AExtended.class;
```

The second one

```
A classB
```

defines a member of type `A` so you can write

```
classB = new A();
classB = new AExtended();
```

Comment: This is good too. It shows how you cannot instantiate a class of type `Class`. You just don't go into detail about what you can do with type `Class` vs an actual instance of that class.